# sudo apt update gives Bus error only

Tags: apt, software-installation

When I type

```
sudo apt-get update
```

or

```
sudo apt update
```

or just

```
sudo apt
```

Only thing in terminal I get is: Bus error

Edit: I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS \n \l

How do I make it work?

Edit 2: I've just seen that unknown command shouldn't give Bus error (core dumped) and in my case it does.

Edit 3: When I type any sudo command password is required and after that "Bus error" occurs. When I type "sudo ls" result is okay. I don't have any clue why this happened. Before this problem I had problem with starting system but solved it few weeks before this one started appearing.

Comment: That's all it says? "Bus error (core dumped)" and *nothing* else at all? Does the system ask for your password first? What happens if you use sudo for anything else? Like `sudo ls` ... does that work? What do you mean by 'unknown command'?

Comment: @user535733 yeah, it requires password and later gives only "Bus error". In case of "sudo ls" it works fine.

Comment: Please edit information into your Question, not into comments. Many folks who might know the answer don't read the comments. Also, avoid shortcut worlds like 'it'. We are not there - we cannot easily tell which 'it' you are referring to. Do you have any idea what you might have damaged? Or what you were attempting to do when the damage occurred? If not, the simplest solution might be to backup your data and reinstall Ubuntu. Bus errors can be tricky and time-consuming to trace.

Comment: @user535733 I've read somewhere that this can be several tricky problems, so I think that I'll reinstall Ubuntu. Thanks for tips for editing questions and answer.